# Android Deflator Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, android, zlib

I want to compress byte array before saving to the file.
When I use Deflator to compress byte array, I get `OutOfMemoryError`:

```
ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(16065): Out of memory on a 921616-byte allocation.
```

[I check the code and it is the same as android developer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/zip/Deflater.html). But I added `DeflatorOutputStream` to reduce memory usage.

My code:

```
public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {

    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    deflater.finish();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    DeflaterOutputStream dos=new DeflaterOutputStream(outputStream);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count=deflater.deflate(buffer); 
        // returns the generated code... index
        dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    deflater.end();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();

    dos.finish();
    dos.close();
    outputStream.close();

    return output;
}
```

I checked that error occurs in this line: `int count=deflater.deflate(buffer);`

Comment: The DeflaterOutputStream will do deflation again! So you're compressing twice.

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't fix Out of Memory error

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a much simpler solution:

```
public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    try (DeflaterOutputStream out = new DeflaterOutputStream(bout)) {
        out.write(data);
    }

    return bout.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Then I assume either your data array is too large or too much memory is consumed somewhere before. How big is you data array?

Comment: 1500kb before compress and 400kb after compress. I call compress function every 100ms. May be memory has no time to release?

Comment: I add folowing code: byte[] res=bout.toByteArray(); bout.close(); and after that error disappeared

Comment: OK. But that's strange as the try-with-resource statement closes the DeflaterOutputStream when leaving which delegates close to the ByteArrayOutputStream...